# Excercise about statistics math

Tags: statistics

The problem is the following:

The number of books bound daily by an automatic machine follows a random variable whose distribution is unknown, with a standard deviation of $20$ books per day. A random sample of $36$ days is selected. Find the probability that the mean number of bound books on those days is at most $4$ books from the true population mean.

From this I understand that we have to calculate the probability that the absolute value of the difference between the arithmetic mean value and the expected value of the numbers of bound books per day is less than or equal to $4$.

I tried writing the definitions, but I don't have the probability law neither the number of books per day.
I tried a more theoretical approach by expressing the requested probability as the sum over $X$ from $0$ to $N$ (values that can take the expected value, where $N$ is the total books bound during the $36$ days) of the sum of $j$ from $1$ up to $4$ (counting the cases where each value corresponds to the difference we need) of the probability that the expected value is $X$ product the probability that the mean value, is $x+j$ plus $x-j$ and adding the case where both are equal to $X$. But again I don't know any probability distribution.

Comment: Do you know the Central Limit Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could be wrong about this, but I don't think you actually need to know the PDF or $\mu_X$ to answer the problem you stated:

> The number of books bound daily by an automatic machine follows a random variable whose distribution is unknown, with a standard deviation of 20 books per day. A random sample of 36 days is selected. Find the probability that the mean number of bound books on those days is at most 4 books from the true population mean.

My reasoning is that if we have a random variable $X$ whose distribution is unknown, with a mean of $\mu_X$ and standard deviation of $\sigma_X$, then the [central limit theorem](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/the-central-limit-theorem-for-sums/) still tells us that if we draw random samples of size $n$, then (as $n$ increases) the random variable $Y = \sum X$ tends to be normally distributed, where $\sum X$ represents sums of $X$.  So symbolically, we get

$$Y \sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y)$$
where $\mu_Y = n \cdot \mu_X$ and $\sigma_Y = \sqrt{n} \cdot \sigma_X$.  So our equation for a particular z-score for $Y = y$ would be this:

$$\begin{align}
z_Y   &= \frac{y - \mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} 
\\ &= \frac{\sum x - n \cdot \mu_X}{\sqrt{n} \cdot \sigma_X} 
\end{align} 
$$
At first I thought we couldn't get a numeric answer for the question since $\mu_X$ is unknown, but then I changed my mind once I played with the algebra.  Just like you, I also got the impression that

> Find the probability that the mean number of bound books on those days is **at most 4 books** from the true population mean.

implied they were looking for $P\left( \left| \overline{ X} - \mu_X \right| \leq 4 \right)$.  After I played around with some algebraic manipulations, this is the clean version of what I got:

$$\begin{align}
P\left( \left| \overline X - \mu_X \right| \leq 4 \right) &= 
P\left( -4 \leq \overline X - \mu_X  \leq 4 \right) \\
&= P\left( -4 \leq \frac{\sum X}{n} - \mu_X  \leq 4 \right) \\
&= P\left( -4 \cdot n \leq \sum X - n \cdot \mu_X  \leq 4 \cdot n \right) \\
&= P\left( \frac{-4 \cdot n}{\sqrt n \cdot \sigma_X} 
\leq \frac{\sum X - n \cdot \mu_X}{\sqrt n \cdot \sigma_X}  \leq \frac{4 \cdot n} {\sqrt n \cdot \sigma_X} \right) \\
&= P\left( \frac{-4 \cdot \sqrt n}{\sigma_X} 
\leq Z_Y
\leq \frac{4 \cdot \sqrt n} {\sigma_X} \right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Since we know $n = 36$ and $\sigma_X = 20$, we get this: $$\frac{4 \cdot \sqrt n}{\sigma_X} = \frac{4 \cdot \sqrt {36}}{20} = \frac{24}{20} = \frac{6}{5} = 1.2$$ Which implies we need to find
$$\begin{align}
P\left( \frac{-4 \cdot \sqrt n}{\sigma_X} 
\leq Z_Y
\leq \frac{4 \cdot \sqrt n} {\sigma_X} \right) 
&= P\left( -1.2 
\leq Z_Y
\leq 1.2 \right)
\\& = P \left( \left| Z_Y \right| < 1.2 \right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Putting this into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=P%28+%7CZ%7C+%3C+1.2%29), I got $P\left(\left| Z_Y\right| < 1.2 \right) \approx 0.7699$.

Personally, I find it really interesting that we can even figure this out for a random variable with an unknown distribution. Guess it just goes to show how powerful the central limit theorem really is.

Comment: Welcome! Good answer. I’m making this comment not to criticise you but just to make you aware that many users consider low quality questions like these (3 downvotes!) not worth answering; there is “enforcement of quality standards” on this site to deter low effort posts, so you might find users downvoting your answer - not because it’s bad, but because we think the OP should have shown more work from themselves first.

Comment: @FShrike, oh, thanks for the info, that's good to know.  I'll try to be mindful of not answering down-voted questions in the future. 